# puppeteer, select li tag or option not working

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to pick item from drop down list using Puppeteer, I tried multiple ways but didn't work.
After viewing the source code I found two times mentioned for the drop down, one in ul and li tag and the the other part in select options tag.

**First one:**
[image]

**Second one**
[image]

I hope get help to solve this, and will appreciated

```
await page.waitForSelector('#Type_Watches');
await page.waitForTimeout(10000);
await page.select('#Type_Watches', 'Casio')
```

Comment: it's pretty common for a custom control to be generated from a `select` element, and then just hide the select element.

Comment: which means, you need to affect the custom control (the ul/li elements), and for that you'll need to simulate all the mouse clicks and keyboard entry